# Mongodb find() with conditions doesn't work

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb

I have multiple documents in a collection , and I want to get all documents which have a specific field value.

```
mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var db = client.db(useDB);

                    let arrayFind = [];
                    let var1 = 'id12345';
                    var cursor = db.collection('somecoll').find({},{"targetField":var1});
                    cursor.forEach(function (result) {
                        arrayFind.push(result);
                    }, function (error) { 
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log(arratFind);
                 });
});
```

But arrayFind is not filtered and I have ALL documents from my collection. How I put all documents in a array ? Do I need to filter it again with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 db.collection('somecoll').find({},{"targetField":var1})
```

need to become:

```
  db.collection('somecoll').find({"targetField":var1})
```

Answer (score 0):

as @R2D2 pointed out the query is wrong.
Also,

```
db.collection.find()
```

returns an array result. Why do you want to push it in an array again?

Comment: because I thought data was added to a "cursor" that you need to iterate inside after.